# Ruby simple Web Service client performing a call to Solr

Tags: ruby, solr, webservice-client

I need some help in doing this: I have to build the following URL in order to perform a query aganst an Apache Solr instance:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/select?q=*%3A*&fq=deal_discount%3A[20+TO+*]&fq=deal_price%3A[*+TO+100]&fq={!geofilt+pt%3D45.6574%2C9.9627+sfield%3Dlocation_latlng+d%3D600}
```

As you can see, the URL contains 3 times the parameter named "fq". What I'm just wondering is how to use the URI.parse() method if I need to pass three times the parameter "fq" within the Hash that is the second argument of the parse() method.

Here's a simple snippet:

```
path = 'http://localhost:8080/solr/select'
pars = { 'fq' => 'deal_price [* TO 100]', 'fq' => '{!geofilt pt=45.6574,9.9627 sfield=location_latlng d=600}' } # This is obviously wrong!
res = Net::HTTP::post_form( URI.parse(path), pars )
```

The solution would be passing the full URL as a String, but I cannot find a method that provide this kind of signature.

Could you please post a simple solution to my problem? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: why not use rsolr or sunspot gem ?

Comment: Just because I'm not for requiring gems if I could do what I want in standard Ruby using a few lines of code. I managed to do it in just 5 lines of code.

Comment: this is just the call to Solr. You would need quite a processing to read the consume the solr xml response as the components results, facets and highlights are different elements.

Comment: Of course, you're right... but I omitted to say this is a web service (that acts as a Solr client) to send the response back to the real consumer. This is a web service that just acts as a bridge between Solr and the consumer. So I just need to forward the HTTP Response to the consumer.

Answer (score 1):

Thaks for your help. Yes, you're right... A get method was what I need. Anyway I had to make a little change to your code because Net:HTTP.get() threw an exception "Unknown method hostname"

```
uri = URI(solrUrl)
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) {|http|
   http.request(req)
}
```

This solved my problem. Thanks indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL suggest that you should use HTTP GET to query solr while your snippet uses POST so that is one thing to change. But I think your main problem is with the parameters, a Hash may only contain one entry for a key so you can't use a Hash in this case. One easy way is to construct the URL by hand.

```
params_array = ['deal_price [* TO 100]', 
  '{!geofilt pt=45.6574,9.9627 sfield=location_latlng d=600}']
base_url = "http://localhost:8080/solr/select"
query_string = "?fq=#{params_array.join('&fq=')}"
url = base_url + query_string
result = Net::HTTP.get url
```

A bit compact maybe - a more readable version may be (according to taste):

```
params_array = ['deal_price [* TO 100]', 
  '{!geofilt pt=45.6574,9.9627 sfield=location_latlng d=600}']
url = "http://localhost:8080/solr/select&"
params_array.each do |param|
  url << "&fq=#{param}"
end
result = Net::HTTP.get url
```